# "On top of each other" in use

Tags: word-usage

There's A and B.

I put A at the bottom, and put B on top of A.

In this situation, can I say "I piled them on top of each other"?

Comment: Yes, but it's more likely to be used when there are more than two items.

Comment: You are  attempting to apply an overly rigid analysis of meaning.  There is vagueness in natural language, and perhaps you have difficulty in processing vagueness.  You might learn about the paradox of the heap.  If you have a heap of sand, and you remove a single grain, it is still a heap.  But one grain of sand is not a heap.  So when did it change?  The resolution is simple.  The word "heap" is vague.  All natural language is vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:  Here is [an example](https://depositphotos.com/photo/two-sisters-laying-down-on-top-of-each-other-and-smiling-in-the-park-20205279.html)

[image]

This image is captioned "Two sisters laying down on top of each other".  But is is more common to use this description with more than two objects. It is particularly unusual if the two objects are significantly different.  So "I put the cup on top of the saucer" but not "I put the cup and saucer on top of each other".  Note that in the image, if the positions of the girls were reversed, it would still be "two sisters on top of each other".

Comment: It should, of course, say **lying down**!